# Rotate text in pdfbox with java

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, pdfbox

I would like to rotate the text with pdfbox that will be above a line as in the picture

[image]

Comment: Please include the code that you used to draw the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*As you did not supply your line drawing code, I here draw a line myself. You might have to adapt this to your situation.*

To rotate text above the line, you have to change the text matrix or the current transformation matrix to rotate following content, e.g. like this:

```java
PDDocument doc = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
doc.addPage(page);
PDPageContentStream cos = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page);
cos.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(-Math.PI / 6, 100, 650));
cos.moveTo(0, 0);
cos.lineTo(125, 0);
cos.stroke();
cos.beginText();
String text = "0.72";
cos.newLineAtOffset(50, 5);
cos.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
cos.showText(text);
cos.endText();
cos.close();
doc.save("TextOnLine.pdf");
doc.close();
```

*([RotatedTextOnLine](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RotatedTextOnLine.java#L34) test `testRotatedTextOnLineForCedrickKapema`)*

I chose to use the current transformation matrix because that allowed me to rotate a horizontal line together with the text.

The result:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: If you have only the points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), use `Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1)` to get the angle, and `Math.sqrt(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)) + ((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)))` to get the line length.

Comment: when we make the rotationInstance, we need to put wich data in the tx and ty ?

Comment: @Michel *"when we make the rotationInstance, we need to put wich data in the tx and ty ?"* - according to the javadocs, `getRotateInstance` returns *A new matrix with the rotation and the x/y translating*. So this method actually returns a translate-and-rotate instance. Thus, if you only want to rotate around the current coordinate system origin, use 0,0.